# XPath outputs .07 * 100 * 100 as 700.00000000000011 why?

Tags: xslt, xpath, precision

I have noticed some strange precision behaviour that I cannot understand, I have some XML:

```
<CLD>
    <UCRV>
        <UCR1>.07</UCR1>
    </UCRV>
</CLD>
```

And in an XSLT file, I am selecting the value as pence (or 100 pence as it seems, I don't know why but it's what the customer wants!) as:

```
<xsl:value-of select="./s0:CLD/s0:UCRV/s0:UCR1/text() * 100 * 100"/>
```

But this is output as 700.00000000000011 The data type is xsd:Decimal. Is there some default precisioning going on here? I can simply round the number but I just wanted to understand it a bit better.

Thanks

Comment: As input? Yes they work fine as does 0.7. I understand it now from the other answers. Cheers

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Floating point numbers can't represent everything precisely. Since the numbers are stored in binary form, numbers that seem to be easy to write in decimal can be actually only approached in binary sometimes. This is the case with 0.07, it's stored internally as 0.070000000000000011 as it seems in your case. As a rule of thumb, you should never trust floating point values so as to compare them directly without rounding.

Answer (score 4):

**As people already explained, the only numeric type used in XPath is xs:double**.

The **[`number()`](http://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xpath-19991116/#function-number)** function converts a value to a double. Therefore, operations on numbers in XPath 1.0 can and sometimes do lead to loss of precision.

**There exist different solutions**:

1. Use the **[`round()`](http://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xpath-19991116/#function-round)** function. One can also use the **[`floor()`](http://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xpath-19991116/#function-floor)** or the **[`ceiling()`](http://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xpath-19991116/#function-ceiling)** functions.
2. Use the XSLT **[`format-number()`](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#function-format-number)** function() or the **[`<xsl:number>`](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#number)** instruction.

**Do note that XPath 2.0 supports all XSD numeric types**, including `xs:decimal`. An XPath 2.0 expression that doesn't cause loss of precision is:

```
xs:decimal(0.07)*100*100
```

Comment: In fact, in XPath 2.0 the numeric literal 0.07 is an xs:decimal, so the cast to xs:decimal is unnecessary. However, reading an attribute whose value is "0.07" gives you an xs:double, unless you are doing schema-aware processing and the schema gives the type as xs:decimal.

Answer (score 3):

This is standard floating point maths. In this there is a maximun number of bits to fit the number and the number is held in scientific form in binary. Here 0.07 cannot be represented exactly and is held as  0.070000000000000011.

For more see many questions on SO (albeit in other languages) using tag [floating-point](/questions/tagged/floating-point), [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point) and [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html)